# Submodules of tensor representations

Tags: representation-theory

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field and $T$ the tensor algebra $T=\bigoplus_{n\geq 0} T_n,$ where $T_n=V^{\otimes n}$. It's easy to see that $T$ can be viewed as a $GL(V)$-module, as $V$ is the natural module for $GL(V)$. Moreover, each $T_n$ is a $GL(V)$-submodule of $T$. This is called the *$n^{th}$ tensor representation.*

Can we do something analogous conversely, where we can view *any* $GL(V)$-module as a submodule of some $T^n$? This is surely not true for $GL(V)$ as a whole, but what about if we place certain restrictions, that is, for a finite subgroup $G\subset GL(V)$, can we say any simple $k[G]$-module is a submodule of some $T_n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true for $\text{GL}(V)$, but there is a salvage. As a $\text{GL}(V)$-representation, the decomposition of $V^{\otimes n}$ is described by [Schur-Weyl duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Weyl_duality), and in particular it is a direct sum of [Schur functors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_functor) $S^{\lambda}(V)$. The Schur functors applied to $V$ describe all *polynomial* $\text{GL}(V)$-representations (those on which $M \in \text{GL}(V)$ acts by matrices with entries polynomial in the entries of $M$). (I need some assumptions on the underlying field; I think characteristic zero suffices?)

Non-polynomial representations include, for example, $M \mapsto |\det(M)|^r$ for real $r$ if the base field is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$; these can never occur as a subrepresentation of $V^{\otimes n}$. In other words, we really want to think about $\text{GL}(V)$ as an [algebraic group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_group) here.

For finite groups we have the following classical exercise.

**Theorem:** Let $G$ be a finite group and $V$ a faithful complex representation of $G$. Then every irreducible representation of $G$ occurs as a subrepresentation of $V^{\otimes n}$ for some $n$.

See, for example, [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18194/faithful-representations-and-tensor-powers). The result generalizes to an algebraically closed base field of characteristic zero and this can probably be weakened. For compact groups the above generalizes as follows.

**Theorem:** Let $G$ be a compact group and $V$ a faithful complex representation of $G$ (so $G$ is a Lie group). Then every irreducible representation of $G$ occurs as a subrepresentation of $V^{\otimes n} \otimes V^{\ast \otimes m}$ for some $n, m$.

See, for example, [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58633/does-every-irreducible-representation-of-a-compact-group-occur-in-tensor-products). Note also that if the image of $G$ lies in $\text{SL}(V)$, then $\Lambda^{\dim V - 1}(V) \cong V^{\ast}$ (exercise), so $V^{\ast}$ is contained in a tensor power of $V$ and we get the same result as before, with no need to take the dual.

Comment: Great answer. I wasn't aware this was a classical argument coming from faithful representations. Do you have any advice for text references to these, or does this come up frequently in most representation theory texts overall?

Comment: I don't know. I learned this material on the internet. I think it's all somewhere in Etingof's notes on representation theory (http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf), possibly excluding the last result.